# How to quicky create array from  big file?

Tags: python

I have example:

```
    for line in IN.readlines():
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        mas = line.split('\t')
        row = ( int(mas[0]), int(mas[1]), mas[2], mas[3], mas[4] )
        self.inetnums.append(row)
    IN.close()
```

If ffilesize == 120mb, script time = 10 sec. Can I decrease this time ?

Comment: You're reading a 120GB file into memory? How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: What hard drive does 12GB/sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may gain some speed if you use a List Comprehension

```
inetnums=[(int(x) for x in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')) for line in fin]
```

Here is the profile information with two different versions

```
>>> def foo2():
    fin.seek(0)
    inetnums=[]
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        mas = line.split('\t')
        row = ( int(mas[0]), int(mas[1]), mas[2], mas[3])
        inetnums.append(row)


>>> def foo1():
    fin.seek(0)
    inetnums=[[int(x) for x in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')] for line in fin]

>>> cProfile.run("foo1()")
         444 function calls in 0.004 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.004    0.004 <pyshell#362>:1(foo1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      220    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'seek' of 'file' objects}
      220    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}


>>> cProfile.run("foo2()")
         664 function calls in 0.006 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.006    0.006 <pyshell#360>:1(foo2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.006    0.006 <string>:1(<module>)
      220    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
      220    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'rstrip' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'seek' of 'file' objects}
      220    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}


>>>
```

Comment: Would you actually gain some speed by using list comps, other than the speed gained by removing `readlines`? It seems to me like its just another way of writing the same code.

Comment: @jamylak: Consider the fact that you won't be calling append multiple times in a loop. I have updated my answer with information from cProfile.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `readlines()`

Just do

```
for line in IN:
```

Using `readlines` you are creating a list of all lines from the file and then accessing each one, which you don't need to do. Without it the for loop simply uses the generator which returns a line each time from the file.